# For and Foreach loop and return with Set. First recurring number in array

Tags: javascript, foreach, return, recurrence, for-in-loop

My question is about return result from these loops. Here is my code.
Function should accept array as an input and return first recurring number in it. I decided to use Set object here.

```
const arr1 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 6, 9]; 

  const recurring = (arr) => {

    const set = new Set();

    // This returns undefined
    arr.forEach(el => {
      if (set.has(el)) {
        return el;
      } else {
        set.add(el); 
      }   
    })       

    // This returns 2
    for (let el in arr) {
     if (set.has(arr[el])) {
       return arr[el];
     } else {
       set.add(arr[el]); 
     }   
    } 

  }

    recurring(arr1); // Should return 2
```

In a first case with forEach loop everything works just fine, I can console.log both Set and el and I can see it, but it returns undefined for some reason.

In a second case with for in loop everything also works but it actually returns the value.

Is there big of a difference between these loops in case of return keyword?
What am I missing?

Comment: The `.forEach()` function completely ignores returned values from the callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact the problem with **[`.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** is that its `callback` function always return `undefined`, even if you use a `return` statement.

If you check the **[`forEach()` method MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** you can see that:

> `forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike `map()` or `reduce()` **it always returns the value `undefined` and is not chainable**.

So in your case `return el;` inside `forEach()` callback is always ignored, and inside the `forEach` callback `return` is specific to this scope that's why the `function` won't return anything.

**Solution:**

If you want to do it with `forEach()`, what you can do is to store this `flag` in  a variable so you can return it after the `forEach()` block:

```
const recurring = (arr) => {

  const set = new Set();
  let result;
  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (set.has(el)) {
       result = !result ? el : result;
      return;
    } else {
      set.add(el);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
const arr1 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 6, 9];

const recurring = (arr) => {

  const set = new Set();
  let result;

  arr.forEach(el => {
    if (set.has(el)) {
      result = !result ? el : result;
      return;
    } else {
      set.add(el);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(recurring(arr1));
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of using `forEach`, you are passing in an anonymous function.  Within that scope, the return will exit that `forEach` function and your wrapper function `recurring` will continue to execute the below code.

In the second example, you are not creating another function so the return applies to the `recurring` function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return something in the function and you need to take `find` instead of `forEach`, because the last one does not respect any return value.

```js
const arr1 = [2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 6, 9];

const recurring = (arr) => {
    const set = new Set();
    return arr.find(el => {
        if (set.has(el)) return true;
        set.add(el);
    });
};

console.log(recurring(arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, keep things simple :

```
const recurring = (arr) => {
    for(let r = 0; r < arr.length; r++){
        if(arr.indexOf(arr[r],r+1)>-1)return arr[r];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are increasing execution time by performing a second search through the array.  O(n) vs O(n²)